# Getting a BeanCreationException caused by an AnnotationException

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate

Im relatively new to Java and Spring. I followed [this](https://www.codeburps.com/post/spring-boot-form-login) simple Spring security tutorial which all works fine, then I started adding my own code, but I'm getting a BeanCreationException saying Round is not an Entity, but it is an entity. I've researched to try and find out what is happening here but I can't figure it out. All other entities are created in MySql and they are basically the same the only difference is Round is the only one linked to a User. Thanks in advance.

User

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Round> rounds = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(String name, String email, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String password, List<Role> roles, List<Round> rounds) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
        this.rounds = rounds;
    }

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        this.roles.add(role);
    }

    public void addRound(Round round) {
        this.rounds.add(round);
    }
}
```

Round

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "round")
public class Round {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "round_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long roundId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "round_id", referencedColumnName = "round_id")
    private List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "round_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date roundDate;

    @Column(name = "round_total")
    private int total;

    public void addScoreToRound(Score score) {
        this.scores.add(score);
    }
```

Error

```
2023-03-05T20:08:34.058+01:00 ERROR 34998 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Association 'com.springSecurityLogin.login.model.User.rounds' targets the type 'com.springSecurityLogin.discgolf.model.Round' which is not an '@Entity' type
2023-03-05T20:08:34.059+01:00  WARN 34998 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Association 'com.springSecurityLogin.login.model.User.rounds' targets the type 'com.springSecurityLogin.discgolf.model.Round' which is not an '@Entity' type
2023-03-05T20:08:34.061+01:00  INFO 34998 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-03-05T20:08:34.107+01:00  INFO 34998 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-03-05T20:08:34.113+01:00  INFO 34998 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-03-05T20:08:34.155+01:00  INFO 34998 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-05T20:08:34.211+01:00 ERROR 34998 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Association 'com.springSecurityLogin.login.model.User.rounds' targets the type 'com.springSecurityLogin.discgolf.model.Round' which is not an '@Entity' type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1752) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at com.springSecurityLogin.login.SpringSecurityLoginApplication.main(SpringSecurityLoginApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association 'com.springSecurityLogin.login.model.User.rounds' targets the type 'com.springSecurityLogin.discgolf.model.Round' which is not an '@Entity' type
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.detectManyToManyProblems(CollectionBinder.java:2544) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:2097) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1524) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1782) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1739) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar:6.0.5]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I see both entities mentioned in the stacktrace are from different package. Maybe to make things simple, put them to the same package first?

Comment: is there a particular reason for using different packages for User (`com.springSecurityLogin.login.model.User`) and Round (`com.springSecurityLogin.discgolf.model.Round`)? I am asking because - maybe - the `com.springSecurityLogin.discgolf` package is not scanned. I cannot say for sure because it depends on your configuration, but, for example, can you try moving `Round` in the  `.login.model` package to see if this is the case?

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah it was a package issue, the discgolf folder was outside the login folder. Sorry and thanks.